# Can't figure out whether my algo is correct

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm trying to code a method (school...) that takes a number `x` and an index `i` as parameters. We want our method to return the digit at the `i` index of the number `x` in decimal representation. The indices are counted as `1` for the last digit, counting backwards.

```
static int k_eme(int x, int i) {

    for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
        x /= 10;
    }
    return x%10;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(k_eme(2049, 4));
}
```

For instance :

```
int number = 2048; 
int index = 1;

k_eme(number, index); // returns 8
k_eme(2189, 3); // returns 1
```

It's an algorithm exercise, so try not to provide answers that contain too many Java built-in methods.

Comment: `return Character.digit(String.valueOf(x).charAt(i), 10);`

Comment: Elliot's solution isn't exactly what you need, but it's close. You need the string's `length() - i` to compute the index counting from the right-hand side.

Comment: is there any problem with your algorithm? not sure about negative numbers (maybe `Math.abs` before returning or starting calculation), but seems OK for me

Comment: Your algorithm works for me.  If you wanted to do this millions of times it would be worth precomputing an array of powers of 10. That way you could do away with the loop and get the i-th digit for the cost of one division and one remainder.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk That's what I was looking for, my algo works, the order of index goes from the right to the left but still working. Thanks for your advice could be interesting your solution but I think I'll stick to mine. When I was testing at first I thought that the index begins from the left that's why I'm here. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Mikael, I think you're on the right track. I believe it's much better to work with integer values, as you have done, instead of converting the number to a string and working with that. Some general advice -- when you ask for help, try to help others help you. Instead of just saying there's a question about this program, give more information about exactly where you see a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` is acceptable number type in Java, that's good.

But if `x` is much bigger number, e.g. `12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031…` (1000 digits), you can't use this algorithm. To handle this, you should use `String` data type and I suggest the following algorithm.

```
    static char getDigit(String N, int d) {  
        return N.charAt(N.length() - d);  
    }

    static char getDigit(int N, int d) {
        String str = String.valueOf(N);
        return str.charAt(str.length() - d);  
    }
```